# Launching App Remotely throws 'Unauthorized' Exception

Tags: hololens

I'm attempting to use the C# Windows Device Portal Wrapper to remotely launch a Hololens app from a PC. However, my code as posted below is throwing an 'Unauthorized' exception. From the Device Portal Wrapper source, it seems this exception is used for incorrect or missing credentials. However, I am 100% certain the credentials I'm using are correct.

`private async Task LaunchApplication()
    {
        try
        {
            Debug.Log("Launching...");
            await portal.LaunchApplicationAsync(appid, packageName);
            Debug.Log("Launched");
        }
        catch (DevicePortalException e)
        {
            Debug.Log(e.Reason);
        }
    }`

I am running this code as a UWP from the Unity Editor. According to the debug output, the Device Portal connection is successfully established, so there shouldn't be any issues there...

I'm not terribly experienced as a developer (college student), so I may be missing something obvious, but any help would be appreciated nonetheless! Thanks

Comment: This should absolutely work.  Please post an issue on the [GitHub tracker](https://github.com/Microsoft/WindowsDevicePortalWrapper/) and one of us will help debug through this.

Comment: Will do, @HirschSinghal. Thank you!